# A Python Programming Road Block Type Error: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable How to Fix

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#colors
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
#Screen Display
Width = 1000
Height = 500
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Trock')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
S_1= pygame.image.load('S1.png')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(S_1,(x,y))

x = (Width * 0)
y = (Height * 0.3)

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            crashed = True
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    S_1(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick (60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I am Trying to load and image onto the display screen (image is called `S1` and variable is `S_1`) but it wont show and says

> Pygame.Surface object is not callable.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You cannot display the image with `S_1(x,y)`, try with `gameDisplay.blit(S_1,(x,y))` maybe ?

Comment: YESS THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

`S_1` is a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) object. Use [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) to draw an image. Actually `blit` draws one `Surface` onto another. Hence you need to `blit` the image onto the *Surface* associated to the display.

```py
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Width, Height))

# [...]

S_1 = pygame.image.load('S1.png')

# [...]

while not crashed:
    # [...]

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    gameDisplay.blit(S_1, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()

    # [...]
```

See also [How to Display Sprites in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348409/how-to-display-sprites-in-pygame/65368394#65368394)