# How to Display Sprites in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

This is just a quick question regarding sprites in PyGame, I have my image loaded as in the code below, and I'm just wondering how to display the sprite in PyGame like drawing a rectangle or circle. I don't want to have it behave in anyway. I think I use a `blit` command, but I'm not sure and I'm not finding much online.

Here's my image code for loading it.

```py
Star = pygame.image.load('WhiteStar.png').convert_alpha()
```

You could just provide an outline for loading a sprite. I simply want to display it.

Comment: You need to ```blit``` the image onto your screen surface. Something like ```pygame.Surface.blit(Star, screen)``` where ```screen``` is your pygame display variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) to draw an image. Actually `blit` draws one [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) onto another. Hence you need to `blit` the image onto the *Surface* associated to the display.
You need to specify the position where the image is `blit` on the target. The position can be specified by a pair of coordinates that define the top left position. Or it can be specified by a rectangle, only taking into account the top left point of the rectangle:

```py
screen = pygame.dispaly.set_mode((width, height))
star = pygame.image.load('WhiteStar.png').convert_alpha()

# [...]

while run:
    # [...]

    screen.blit(star, (x, y))

    # [...]
```

---

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) when you want to place the center of a surface at a specific point. [`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position. The position of the rectangle can be specified by a keyword argument. For example, the center of the rectangle can be specified with the keyword argument `center`. These keyword argument are applied to the attributes of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) before it is returned (see [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for a full list of the keyword arguments):

```py
screen.blit(star, star.get_rect(center = (x, y)))
```